# cdktf errors our on get operation

Tags: terraform, terraform-cdk

working from a Mac the cdktf get is failing with error below. Deployed a docker instance (that has alpine image) and get the same error on cdktf get, On another machine(WSL instance) was not getting this error. cdktf --version, gives the right version, 0.13.2

Any recommendation to resolve this error?

```
NOTE: Temp directory retained due to an error: /tmp/temp-mIpJCb
Error: jsii compilation failed with non-zero exit code: 1
  | [2023-02-22T22:52:01.455] [ERROR] jsii/compiler - Compilation errors prevented the JSII assembly from being created
  | warning JSII6: A "peerDependency" on "constructs" at "10.1.257" means you should take a "devDependency" on "constructs" at "10.1.257" (found "undefined")
  | warning JSII6: A "peerDependency" on "cdktf" at "0.13.2" means you should take a "devDependency" on "cdktf" at "0.13.2" (found "undefined")
  | warning JSII3: There is no "README.md" file. It is required in order to generate valid PyPI (Python) packages.
  | node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/util.d.ts:1485:42 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
  | 1485         entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
  |                                               ~
  | node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/util.d.ts:1485:44 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
  | 1485         entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
  |                                                 ~~~~~~
```

Comment: Does the Typescript version differ between these environments?

Comment: Yes, updated terraform version